# iPhone: How can I access methods, variables, items from another .m file

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller

Rookie Question:
I have my ViewController.m that is getting rather big. What is the way to "off-load" some (general purpose) code to another dot-something file (let's call it myStuff.m)?

Or to rephrase the question:

1. How I call a method from another .m file,
2. How I can access a variable and
3. How I can access an element (UIView) of another .m file.

Example:
In myStuff.m I want to do the following:

```
[ViewController ViewController_Method:@"bla"];
yLocal = ViewController.xRemote;
[ViewController.myText setText:@"bla-bla"];
```

What code do I have to add to my ViewController.m and how should the myStuff.m be set-up to do it?
What is the (easiest) way of doing it?

Comment: I said that it was a "Rookie Question"! I haven't realized that only experts can ask questions in here... (at least the other 2, posted something useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variables**

Declare public variables

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) VariabledatType *myVariablename;
```

**Methods**

Declare public methods

```
-(void)myPublicMethod:(NSString *)perameterString;
```

**Access from another class**

Let consider the variables and methods are the part of Class1

```
Class1Obj.myVariablename //Accessing variables;

Class1Obj.myVariablename = someValuel; //setting values to variables;   

[Class1Obj myPublicMethod:@"myString"]; //calling Methods;
```

Comment: Hm... I added the -(void)myPublicMethod:(NSString *)perameterString; in the Class1Obj.h file, I added the #import "Class1Obj.h" to my myStuff.m file, but still nothing... It says "No known class method for selector 'myPublicMethod'"

Comment: Update: By searching around, I found that if I change my method from -(void)myPublicMethod:(NSString *)perameterString; to +(void)myPublicMethod; it works. It's not what I want, but it compiles. (again, as I said, I am new to this, so maybe I state the obvious here...)

Comment: Well, I finally found it (not thanks to the (other comments)). I had to call the myPublicMethod: like this [appDelegate.viewController myPublicMethod:@"bla"]; where appDelegate was defined like this:     AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need to do some reading up on Objective-C, Object design and Model View Controller (MVC).

Here's some links

[Objective-C tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/learn-objective-c-day-1/)

[MVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)

[Design Fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974)

Check out the Stanford University lectures on iOS development (Paul Hegarty) as well - they are excellent.

Comment: (thanks for the links, they are good as a reference, not very helpful in my situation though.)